# Pandas merge column duplicate and sum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to merge duplicate column and sum their value?

What I have

```
A   30
A   40
B   50
```

What I need

```
A   70
B   50
```

DF for this example

```
d = {'address': ["A", "A", "B"], 'balances': [30, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In another case when you have a dataset with several duplicated columns and you wouldn't want to select them separately use:

```
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 16):

You may use

`df2 = df.groupby(['address']).sum()`

or

`df2 = df.groupby(['address']).agg('sum')`

If there are columns other than `balances` that you want to peak only the `first` or `max` value,  or do `mean` instead of `sum`, you can go as follows:

```
d = {'address': ["A", "A", "B"], 'balances': [30, 40, 50], 'sessions': [2, 3, 4]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df2 = df.groupby(['address']).agg({'balances': 'sum', 'sessions': 'mean'})
```

That outputs

```
         balances   sessions
address       
A              70       2.5  
B              50       4.0
```

You may add `as_index = False` to `groupby` arguments to have:

```
  address  balances  sessions
0       A        70       2.5
1       B        50       4.0
```

Comment: what if for every value in`adresses` the `sessions` value is the same and you just want to keep it?
`{'address': ["A", "A", "B"], 'balances': [30, 40, 50], 'sessions': ["V","V","K"]}` to 
`{'address': ["A", "B"], 'balances': [70, 50], 'sessions': ["V","K"]}`

Comment: @TobiasKolb in that case you can use `'sessions': 'first'` which keeps one of two (or more) `"V"`s

Comment: This answer is more useful than the accepted one!