# Using Pandas.groupby.agg with multiple columns and functions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, groupby

I have a data frame which contains duplicates I'd like to combine based on 1 column (name). In half of the other columns I'd like to keep one value (as they should all be the same) whereas I'd like to sum the others.

I've tried the following code based on an answer I found here: [Pandas merge column duplicate and sum value](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47023/pandas-merge-column-duplicate-and-sum-value/47024#47024?newreg=8d36613941a04a26832fcc82246159f1)

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name']).agg({'address': 'first', 'cost': 'sum'}
```

The only issue is I have 100 columns, so would rather not list them all out. Is there a way to pass a tuple or list in the the place of 'address' and 'cost' above? Something along the lines of

```
column_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
columns_first = tuple(column_list[0:68])
columns_sum = tuple(column_list[68:104])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps generate the dictionary using a list comprehension style syntax. E.g.

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['name']).agg({col: 'first' if i<68 else 'sum' for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)})
```